# rails bootstrap x-editable emptytext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, x-editable

I'm using Bootstrap X-editable in a Rails app. I would like to replace the word `empty` in a table cell with the name of the field.

The X-editable documentation says the `emptytext` will replace it.

But, the following doesn't work - I still get `empty`.

```
<a href="#" class="answer" data-type="textarea" emptytext="Description" data-pk="1" data-resource="task" data-source="/tasks" data-name="longdesc" data-url="/tasks/<%= task.id %> ">
```

This is the javascript:

```
  $(".answer").editable
    placement: 'bottom'
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not `emptytext="Description"` but `data-emptytext="Description"`.

```
<a href="#" class="answer" data-type="textarea" data-emptytext="Description" data-pk="1" data-resource="task" data-source="/tasks" data-name="longdesc" data-url="/tasks/<%= task.id %> ">
```

You can also do it in javascript instead of inline html.

```
$('.answer.description').editable({
    placement: 'bottom',
    emptytext: 'Description'
});
```

**EDIT about HTML5**

Look here about [HTML5 data-attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes). This is why all the x-editable's settings start with data-*.

**EDIT Answering your comment**

You can do like in the official demo [Look at the sex select](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html) with the prepend data (and display tweak):

```
$('#sex').editable({
    prepend: "not selected",
    source: [
        {value: 1, text: 'Male'},
        {value: 2, text: 'Female'}
    ],
    display: function(value, sourceData) {
        var colors = {"": "gray", 1: "green", 2: "blue"},
        elem = $.grep(sourceData, function(o){return o.value == value;});
        if(elem.length) {
            $(this).text(elem[0].text).css("color", colors[value]);
        } else {
            $(this).empty();
        }
    }
});
```

Or you can directly add a sourceData with `{value: 0, text: 'Null'}`

Comment: Quick follow-up question: how can you include nil or blank in a dropdown selection.  In case the user selects a value then wants it to be blank?  Thanks!

Comment: I found it - `data-prepend=""`

Comment: Very useful info @Reddirt

Answer (score 0):

or you can use

```
$('.answer').editable({
placement: 'bottom',
defaultValue: 'Description' // for default value
});
```